# Applying original image pixels wherever the thresholded image is black in OpenCV/numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I've applied some morphological operations on a thresholded image and now I want to convert it back to the original image, but only wherever the image is black. Here's some example pseudocode of what I'm trying to do:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("img01.jpg")
empty_image = np.zeros([img.width,img.height,3],dtype=np.uint8)
grey = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(grey,125,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8) 
mask = cv2.erode(thresh1, kernel, iterations=2)
mask = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel, iterations=2)
for(i in mask):
      if(mask[i]>0]:
          empty_image[i]=img[i]
```

In other terms: How can I restore parts of an original image to parts of a thresholded image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After find the mask just use `result = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img,mask=mask)` with no need to declare an empty image, which is called mask process.

Another way is to use boolean indexing as `img[mask==0] = 0` to make every image pixel zero (black) if it's black in the mask.

And that is the result:

[image: result of apply mask to image]

[This link](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/d86/tutorial_py_image_arithmetics.html) for useful example to understand `bitwise_and` and other simple related operations in `opencv` docs.

Comment: That's exactly what I'd hoped for! Thanks a lot. I didn't really try too hard to look into the for-loop of doing things because for this specific project, O(n) is too slow!

Comment: yes it's the best  to avoid using for loop, you can solve it with slicing as `img[mask==0] = 0` to make every pixel of the original image black if it's black in the mask.